# How can I deal with overflow in C

Tags: c, overflow

I want to make a mathematical **combination calculator** in C. For example, 5 combination 2 is 10. Even though using `unsigned long long` type, There's **overflow** problem occurs in my program. Input sources are n and m. Each of numbers are (5<= n,m <= 100) and (m<=n) bound. In addition, I attach my code beneath. Is there any kind of larger number type or solution which I don't know? Please tell me. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static unsigned long long gcd(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b)
{
if(a<b)
    return gcd(b, a);
if(b==0)
    return a;
return gcd(b, a%b);
}

int main()
{
unsigned long long n, m1, m2, i, j, temp, denominator[101] = {1,}, numerator[101] = {1,}, total_de = 1, total_nu = 1, gcd_result;

scanf("%llu %llu",&n, &m1);
m2 = n - m1;
if(m2 < m1)
{
    temp = m1;
    m1 = m2;
    m2 = m1;
}// m1 is small

denominator[0] = 1; numerator[0] = 1;
for(i=1; i<=m1; i++)
{
    denominator[i] = n--;
    numerator[i] = i;
}

for(i = 1; i<=m1; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j<=m1; j++)
    {
        gcd_result = gcd(denominator[i], numerator[j]);
        denominator[i] /= gcd_result;
        numerator[j] /= gcd_result;
    }
}

for(i = 1; i<=m1; i++)
{
    total_de *= denominator[i];
    total_nu *= numerator[i];
}
// sometimes overflow happened
printf("%llu\n",total_de/total_nu);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: First you should fix your algorithm. It's very inefficient and at first glance seems to require much larger intermediate results than it should.

Comment: @R.. Who cares about intermediate results? If it's not slow, let the compiler deal with it. Don't prematurely optimise.

Comment: @SecurityMatt If the intermediate results are larger than necessary, you have overflow sooner.

Comment: @DanielFischer: They overflow whether they are intermediates written back to named variables, or whether they aren't written back to intermediate variables. At least if you have lots of intermediates it's easier to debug.

Comment: @SecurityMatt R..'s point is that arranging the computation differently leads to smaller intermediate results, and thus to overflow only later.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh, in which case I missed his point. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I can solve this problem using another integer like digit calculator. And I realize my solution is dull :-( Now, my solution using Pascal's triangle to calculate such a large number. Thanks for your help everybody!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a library that allows arbitrary precision, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org).

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle large numbers, but of a known maximum length would be through arrays. You could separate the number into parts and store each part in a separate array element.

Another way would be, for handling large numbers of initially unknown length, using a linked list. The principle remains the same, divide the number into smaller parts and store in separate nodes of the list.

In either case you will have to write your own functions for handling the arithmetic operations that you need to accomplish. Overall, it would make an interesting programming exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

By using Pascal's triangle, I can solve my solution more efficiently. Without using multiplication. And overflow problem is solved by integer separation digits.